# Как найти объект по значению параметра, typeORM

Tags: node.js, typeorm

У меня есть сущность заказов:

```
@Entity('orders')
export class Order {
  @ApiProperty({ example: '1', description: 'Уникальный идентификатор' })
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ApiProperty({ type: () => Client, example: '1', description: 'идентификатор заказчика' })  
  @ManyToOne(() => Client, (client) => client.orders)
  @JoinColumn({name: 'client_id', referencedColumnName: "id"})
  client: Client;

  @ManyToMany((type) => Product, (product) => product.orders)
  @JoinTable({
      name: 'order_product',
      joinColumn: { name: 'order_id' },
      inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'product_id' },
  })
  products: Product[];

  @ApiProperty({ example: '2023-03-28 19:44:18.326569', description: 'дата создания' })
  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @ApiProperty({ example: 'доставлен', description: 'статус заказа' })
  @Column()
  status: string;

  @ApiProperty({ example: '12234', description: 'сумма заказа в рублях' })
  @Column()
  cost: number;
}
  
export default Order;
```

Я пытаюсь создать метод поиска заказов со статусом "доставлен":

```
    async findClosed(): Promise<Order[]> {
        const orders = await this.orderRepository.find({
            where: { status: "доставлен" },
            relations: {
                products: true,
                client: true,
            },
        });
        return orders;
    }
```

Почему-то при попытке вызвать этот метод вылетает следующая ошибка:
error: error: неверный синтаксис для типа integer: "NaN"
[Nest] 13164  - 17.05.2023, 21:01:55   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] неверный синтаксис для типа integer: "NaN"
QueryFailedError: неверный синтаксис для типа integer: "NaN"
То есть почему-то программа пытается искать по id, а не по status параметру. Что я делаю не так?
Формируется вот такая кьюри-строка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш код пробует найти записи по status, с этой точки все нормально. Скорее проблема в самих данных. Посмотрите в бд таблицы orders и все связанные с ней. Вероятно, где-то записан неверный тип